# Can I use ClamAV on GoDaddy shared hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy, linux

My Linux shared hosting (GoDaddy) doesn't have ClamAV installed.  Unfortunately, I'm not a Linux expert; so I don't know exactly what is involved in installing an application on a Linux.  So, my question is:

1. Can I install ClamAV on my shared hosting?
2. If I can't install it, is it possible to still use it somehow?

Comment: Why would you want to run it? I would expect any host worth their snuff to have some form of antivirus/protection, even if it isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

1. No
2. Probably not. It needs to run on the server so unless there is a way to run it virtually, I'm not a hosting guru but I'm pretty sure there's not, you won't be able to do this unless you get a dedicated box or VPS.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. You're on shared hosting, which means you don't have access to the server. You might need to consider your own server such as a VPS or dedicated server.